# Typescript dictionary with readonly keys

Tags: dictionary, typescript, readonly

Is it possible to declare a dictionary class in typescript with readonly keys?

[image: declaration of dictionary class with readonly keys]

Code:

```
class Dictionary {
    readonly[key: string]: string;

    constructor(props: Dictionary) {
        for (const key in props) {
            this[key] = props[key];
        }
    }
}
```

Normally setting the values of readonly properties is allowed in the constructor, but here the compiler complains that "Index signature of type 'Dictionary' only permits reading'.

Comment: should we answer with a screenshot as well?

Comment: if you want to add a screenshot to a valid answer I will appreciate it, but I only added the screenshot to show where the typescript compiler complains. I will add the code as text, ok too late ;) thanks Nitzan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is by design or not, [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#read-only-properties-and-index-signatures) are confusing about this:

> A property or index signature can now be declared with the readonly
>   modifier is considered read-only.

But:

> Read-only properties may have initializers and may be assigned to in
>   constructors within the same class declaration, but otherwise
>   assignments to read-only properties are disallowed

So while both properties and index signature can be readonly, maybe only properties can be assigned in the constructor.
Not sure about it, you can open an issue and find out.

You can however use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) which wouldn't end up with a compilation error and it cleans out the code as well:

```
class Dictionary {
    readonly[key: string]: string;

    constructor(props: Dictionary) {
        Object.assign(this, props);
    }
}

let d1 = new Dictionary({ key1: "one", key2: "two" });
console.log(d1); // Dictionary {key1: "one", key2: "two"}

let d2 = new Dictionary(d1);
console.log(d1); // Dictionary {key1: "one", key2: "two"}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Dictionary%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20readonly%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(props%3A%20Dictionary)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.assign(this%2C%20props)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20d1%20%3D%20new%20Dictionary(%7B%20key1%3A%20%22one%22%2C%20key2%3A%20%22two%22%20%7D)%3B%0Aconsole.log(d1)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Dictionary%20%7Bkey1%3A%20%22one%22%2C%20key2%3A%20%22two%22%7D%0A%0Alet%20d2%20%3D%20new%20Dictionary(d1)%3B%0Aconsole.log(d1)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Dictionary%20%7Bkey1%3A%20%22one%22%2C%20key2%3A%20%22two%22%7D))

---

#### Edit

Using `Object.assign` is better than your for/in loop, here's an example why:

```
class A {
    [key: string]: any;

    constructor() {
        this["k1"] = "v1";
        this["k2"] = "v2";
    }

    method() {}
}

let a = new A();
let a1 = Object.assign({}, a);
console.log(a1); // { k1: "v1", k2: "v2" }

let a2 = {};
for (const key in a) {
    a2[key] = a[key];
}
console.log(a2); // { k1: "v1", k2: "v2", method: () }
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20any%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5B%22k1%22%5D%20%3D%20%22v1%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this%5B%22k2%22%5D%20%3D%20%22v2%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20method()%20%7B%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20A()%3B%0Alet%20a1%20%3D%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20a)%3B%0Aconsole.log(a1)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7B%20k1%3A%20%22v1%22%2C%20k2%3A%20%22v2%22%20%7D%0A%0Alet%20a2%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0Afor%20(const%20key%20in%20a)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20a2%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20a%5Bkey%5D%3B%0A%7D%0Aconsole.log(a2)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7B%20k1%3A%20%22v1%22%2C%20k2%3A%20%22v2%22%2C%20method%3A%20()%20%7D%0A%0Alet%20a3%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0AObject.keys(a).forEach(key%20%3D%3E%20a3%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20a%5Bkey%5D)%3B%0Aconsole.log(a3)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%7B%20k1%3A%20%22v1%22%2C%20k2%3A%20%22v2%22%20%7D))

As you can see, using for/in loop will also iterate over prototype properties, which probably isn't what you want.
`Object.assign` doesn't have this problem.

Another option is to use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
let a3 = {};
Object.keys(a).forEach(key => a3[key] = a[key]);
console.log(a3); // { k1: "v1", k2: "v2" }
```

Comment: ok Object.assign sounds like a valid sollution for now, but I try to avoid it when possible because as you can see here it just overrides the readonly flag. I will open an issue as you suggested

Comment: The issue already exists, feel free to join the discussion https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6781

Comment: But if the constructor would have let you assign values then that would "overrides the readonly flag" as well. Check my revised answer.

Comment: This just strengthens my feeling that it really is an issue with the typescript compiler spec. Of course object assign also iterates over the object keys but then it should come to the same compiler error when Object.assign is called in the constructor.

Comment: Use `Object.setProperty` and make them read-only that way when setting - in effect it's like using the `get` keyword instead of `readonly` (that must be given a value at init though, just in case anyone reading this is trying to make it work). Remember that `readonly` is only a hint, and not actually enforced in any way...

Answer (score 0):

`Object.freeze(...);` prevents changing the object at JS level and creates in Typescript the type `Readonly<T>`. The placeholder ... (T) can be a native dictionary, a `Map<X, Y>`, an array or whatever. So there is no need to implement your own dictionaries, just declare/create with already provided tools.